# IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 - Push notifications polling not working in Production environment

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

My problem is this:

- When in **Development environment**, everything is OK - the poller is working fine, the DB statuses changes, etc.
- When in **Production environment**, nothing appears in the log and nothing changes in the DB (I'm reading notifications from a DB table).

**Push Notifications eventSource:**

```
WL.Server.createEventSource({
    name : 'PushEventSource',
    poll : { 
        interval : 360, 
        onPoll : 'sendNotifications' 
    },
    securityTest : 'mobileSecTest' 
});
```

**mobileSecTest security test:**

```
<mobileSecurityTest name="mobileSecTest"> 
    <testUser realm="LdapAdapterRealm"/>
    <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"/>
</mobileSecurityTest>
```

**sendNotifications() implementation:**

```
var notificationServicesResourceName = "PushAdapter";
function sendNotifications(){

WL.Logger.info('Starting to send notifications');
    var lockInvocationData = {
            adapter : "SQLConnector",
            procedure : "isLocked",
            parameters : [ notificationServicesResourceName ]
    };
    var isLockedResult = WL.Server.invokeProcedure(lockInvocationData);
    if (!isLockedResult.locked) {
        lockInvocationData = {
                adapter : "SQLConnector",
                procedure : "acquireLock",
                parameters : [ notificationServicesResourceName ]
        };
        WL.Server.invokeProcedure(lockInvocationData);

//Get the list of all notifications, from external database
        var dbResponse = getAllUnsentNotifications();

        var data = dbResponse.data ;

        /////////////////THE REST OF THE LONG LONG CODE ////////////
        //Reealse lock
        lockInvocationData = {
                adapter : "SQLConnector",
                procedure : "releaseLock",
                parameters : [ notificationServicesResourceName ]
        };
        WL.Server.invokeProcedure(lockInvocationData);
    }
}
```

**Adapter XML file:**

```
<wl:adapter name="PushAdapter"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration"
    xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http">

    <displayName>PushAdapter</displayName>
    <description>PushAdapter</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>${com.ibm.moi.ci.host}</domain>
            <port>${com.ibm.moi.ci.port}</port> 
        </connectionPolicy>
        <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="300" />
    </connectivity>
    <!-- Replace this with appropriate procedures -->
    <procedure name="sendNotifications"/>
    <procedure name="submitNotification"/>

</wl:adapter>
```

Comment: Are you using `WL.Logger.info('Starting the send notifications');` in the server side ?

Comment: Yes. It outputs logs in my local machine

Comment: It'd be better if you add logs from your production server.

Comment: there is no trace of anything in the logs. I only have this after deploying the adapter : 00000081 DeployService I com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DeployServiceImpl syncAdaptersFromDB FWLSE0084I: Deployed adapter 'PushAdapter' successfully.

Comment: What is the method in which you are invoking the adapter procedure? In other words, what is the URL that is used?

Comment: I think I didn't understand your question but all the missing peace of code is sendNotifications() that access the database and do send the notifications. This method get never called

Comment: What is in sendNotifications? What is the URL it points to in order to fetch and send the message? This function is invoking an adapter procedure, no?

Comment: @IdanAdar I posted an update of the code

Comment: The adapter XML is pointing to the production server?

Comment: @IdanAdar I added a kind a resource locking feature in order to synchronize between cluster nodes so that they don't send the same notifications at the same time. I posted the adapter XML

Comment: That does not answer my question. This variable you are using for the host, is it actually pointing to the production servers?

Comment: Actually it's pointing on a Cast Iron server. But to be honest we call external adapters for connectivity we don't make communication through this adapter. we access SQL through SQLConnector adapter.

Comment: @IdanAdar do you have any idea of what it could be?

Comment: Not at this time; next week people will be back from Christmas vacation and we'll see how it goes then. I will forward this question. Are you an IBM customer or Business Partner (who?)?

Comment: Yes in fact I think you already received an email about this problem (Proxym-IT)

Comment: Yes, I did receive an email about a very similar issue, but from a Business Partner called "iSeed".

Comment: Is the app fully functioning in Production environment and only push notifications fail? I see that you are protecting the proceudre using LDAP, is it working in production? Are you using JMS for the polling or otherwise?

Comment: So to answer the questions : 
We are not using JMS for polling and we would like to avoid using wl_unprotected feature. Ldap authentication is done inside an adapter-based authentication (some specific needs). The application works perfectly in production except the push notifications.

Comment: You say that not even the logging takes places, so it sounds like the function is not being invoked... I'd put some logging before it in key areas in the code and see which is not taking places, perhaps this will help you to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Ok no problem let's do it

Comment: @HoucemBerrayana, results?

Comment: Yeah we got this running. We did nothing. The logs sometimes appear sometimes not. We still have this problem :
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: The resource 'proc:CIAdapter.startOrchestrationForOracle' should only be accessed when authenticated in realm 'wl_antiXSRFRealm'."

Comment: There have been some changes in the cluster settings it's not us who did it but some IBMers. Maybe it starts to show logs because of what they did

Comment: @HoucemBerrayana, any new developments?

Comment: @IdanAdar yes it got fixed yesterday. We opened a PMR and it reached level 3. It was caused by securityTests. We added securityTest="wl_unprotected" in the hole execution chain (across 5 adapters)

Comment: @HoucemBerrayana, Great news. Please write this as an answer and mark as Answered so others could benefit from it.

Comment: I posted it. Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got this running now.
It was a security problem. When you run the application on your local workstation on worklight studio and liberty profile, some security features are disabled which is not the case of the production.

On development mode all the procedures with no explicit securityTest have wl_inprotected by default I think they did it like this in order to be able to invoke procedures from Eclipse. In the production environment the security is enhanced and wl_unprotected is not considered as the default security test.

So what I did is to add securityTest="wl_unprotected" for all the procedures in the execution chain except the sendNotifications procedure which should remain without sec test.

That's it !